# About a form of the Chebyshev's inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, concentration-of-measure

For a function $f$ and a probability measure $P$ and $\forall \delta > 0, \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ it is apparently true that, $$P(\vert f - \mathbb{E}_P [f]\vert > \delta  ) \leq e^{-\lambda \delta }\mathbb{E}_P [e^{\lambda \vert f - \mathbb{E}_P [f] \vert  } ]$$

- This is apparently Chebyshev's inequality. Can someone kindly explain how?

---

If necessary assume that $P$ satisfies a Log Sobolev Inequality and $f$ is Lipschitz.

Comment: What have you tried? And where does it come from, what is the context -- is it a homework question? (at first glance, a good hint seems to be: $\exp$ is increasing, so $\Pr[X > x] = \Pr[e^X > e^x]$; and Markov's inequality.

Comment: No hypothesis needed except that $\lambda\gt0$, then use the identity $$[X>\delta]=[e^{\lambda X}>e^{\lambda \delta}]$$ and the inequality $$\mathbf 1_{Y>y}\leqslant e^{-y}e^Y,$$ to deduce that $$P(X>\delta)\leqslant e^{-\lambda \delta}E(e^{\lambda X}).$$

Comment: @Did What is your Chebyshev inequality that you are using?

Comment: @user6818 He is not suggesting to use Chebyshev's inequality as a blackbox, as far as I can tell -- but instead directly the underlying argument. Do you remember how Chebyshev's inequality is proven? (from Markov's - - and if so, do you remember the proof of Markov's inequality? This is the gist of the argument)

Comment: Indeed, for those of us with not so many memory capacities, to remember that integrating the pointwise inequality $$\mathbf 1_{Y>y}\leqslant e^-ye^Y$$ yields $$P(Y>y)\leqslant E(e^{-y}e^Y)=e^{-y}E(e^Y)$$ is a worthy investment. And yes, this is how Markov inequality and a wealth of similar inequalities are proved: by integrating pointwise inequalities.

Comment: @Did: I agree, knowing the proof by heart is only an substitute for being able to prove it from scratch. But the OP did seem very intent on using Chebyshev's inequality, so I figured that outlining the relation was worth it.